# How to get all the results with "google map" with writing a little python script?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Open page "http://ditu.google.cn". Then I type in search box "school Newyork"

I was thinking of writing a little python scriptI  to get all the search results saved like this:

```
SchoolName
Address
Telephone
site
```

I'm trying to get these informations with BeautifulSoup. The problem is that there are ten results in one page. I don't know how to change to "Next Page" with Python. Is there any way to get all the results?

Comment: A couple of things: Google has an [api that should work better than this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started), and also, [you should probably stick to English when asking for help on the internet](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-ugly-american-programmer.html).

Comment: You could use browser automation to turn pages. Look up Selenium (advanced) or Mechanize (simple console browser)